# TCPDF Issue With Adding Pages

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to add a landscape page in the middle of a portrait PDF generated from HTML. I have set `AutoPageBreak` to `true`, but this results in the pages overlapping when I call `AddPage()`. For example:

```
    $pageBody = "<h1>Test</h1><p>Long content here so that auto page break comes into effect</p>";
    $pageBody .= "<br pagebreak=\"true\" /><h2>Page Two</h2>";
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(170, '', 20, 50, $pageBody, 0, 0, false, true, '', true);
    $pdf->endPage();

    $pageBody2 = "<h1>Test Page 3 Landscape</h1>";
    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(170, '', 20, 50, $pageBody2, 0, 0, false, true, '', true);
    $pdf->endPage();
    $pdf->Output('my.pdf', 'I');
```

That results in the first pages displaying correctly (after being auto page broken), but the second content, `pageBody2`, being overlapped on top of the first set of page(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `$ln` (7th) parameter of the [`writeHTMLCell()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8458280d15b73d3baffb28eebe2d9246) calls in your AutoPageBreak-broken pages from `0` to `1` (or `2`):

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(170, '', 20, 50, $pageBody, 0, 1, false, true, '', true);
```

so that the new landscape page goes to the beginning of the next line (`1`) or below (`2`) the last box of `$pageBody` instead of to the right of it.

Comment: Thank you! Changing it from 0 to 1 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

for adding pagebreak,use

```
<br pagebreak="true"/>
```

or

```
<tcpdf method="AddPage" />
```

Comment: Sorry, should've clarified - I already do this with the first set of content. Updated the question code to reflect.